# UI-Router does not Register Dynamically Created Element with ui-sref

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dynamic, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I created a SPA using UI-Router to manage my the views. The navigation bar was initially a static navbar and the routing worked correctly:

```
<div id="mainNavBar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li ui-sref-active="active" class="dropdown">
            <a ui-sref="alerts" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span> Alerts<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="alerts.map"><span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span> Alert Map</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="alerts.pareto"><span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span> Alert Pareto</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="alerts.history"><span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span> Alert History</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>

        ...

    </ul>
</div>
```

The website was then changed to dynamically populate the navigation bar from a JSON object obtained by querying a database.

```
function generate_header_menu(callback){    
    $.getJSON('php/site_configuration.php', function(layoutData){

        var numberOfCategories = layoutData.categories.length;

        var headerMenu = $('#header_menu');

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCategories; i++){
            console.log(layoutData.categories[i]);

            var categoryItem = $('<li>');
            var categoryItemList = $('<ul>').attr('class','dropdown-menu');

            headerMenu.append(
                categoryItem.attr('ui-sref-active', 'active').attr('class', 'dropdown')
                .append(
                    $('<a>').attr('ui-sref', layoutData.categories[i].uiRouterState).attr('class','dropdown-toggle').attr('data-toggle','dropdown')
                    .append(
                        $('<span>').attr('class', layoutData.categories[i].icon)
                    )
                    .append("&nbsp;&nbsp;" + layoutData.categories[i].name)
                    .append(
                        $('<span>').attr('class', 'caret')
                    )
                )
            );  

            categoryItem.append(categoryItemList);

            var numberOfSubCategories = layoutData.categories[i].subcategories.length;
            for (var j = 0; j < numberOfSubCategories; j++){
                categoryItemList.append(
                        $('<li>').attr('ui-sref-active', 'active')
                        .append(
                            $('<a>').attr('ui-sref', layoutData.categories[i].uiRouterState + "." + layoutData.categories[i].subcategories[j].uiRouterState)
                            .append(layoutData.categories[i].subcategories[j].name)
                        )
                    );
            }

        }

        callback(layoutData);
    })
    .error(
        function() { 
            console.log("Error Obtaining Site Configuration"); 
        }
    );      
}
```

In the second case the ui-sref and ui-sref-active directives are not working. The routing in app.config was the same for both the static and dynamically loaded navigation bar, and when I go to a URL, the correct ui-view is loaded, but the corresponding navigation bar item is not set to active.

Is this because the navigation bar was populated after the web page was loaded? How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that you're using jQuery DOM manipulation with Angular directives. That will not work. You need to understand how an Angular application is bootstrapped and how directives are handled.

See [here](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html):

> #### How directives are born (compilation and instantiation)
>
> When the DOM is done loading and the AngularJS process starts booting up, the first process that happens is the HTML is parsed by the browser as a DOM tree. This tree is then parsed using AngularJS’s $compile() method. $compile runs through the DOM tree and looks for directive declarations for the different DOM elements. Once all directive declarations are found for each DOM element and sorted (by priority, which we’ll get into shortly), the directive’s compile function is run and is expected to return a link() function. The $compile() function will return a linking function that wraps all of the containing DOM element’s directives’ linking functions.
>
> Finally, the linking function is invoked with the containing scope
>   that attaches all of the associated directives to that scope. This is
>   where we’ll do most of the work when building directives, as this is
>   where we can register listeners, set up watches, and add
>   functionality. The result of this process is why the live data-binding
>   exists between the scope and the DOM tree.

If you want to make dynamic `ui-sref`s, go ahead and bind the `sref`s to a list of some sort:

```
<a ui-sref="sref" ng-repeat="sref in srefs">{{sref}}</s>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.srefs = ['linka','linkb','linkc']; //Populated from your API response
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it :)